# on osx, docker run -v $(pwd):... does not get expanded

Tags: macos, docker

On OSX, when running a docker container and mounting the current directory, the expression `$(pwd)` does not get expanded:

`bash
docker run -v $(pwd):/var/mydir image`

On the container, `/var/mydir` remains empty.

I have installed bash-completion via homebrew, and the docker-specific bash completion also.

I see examples of using `$(pwd)` on OSX all over the place, and yet I cannot make it work.

Please note that the current directory is under `/Users`, e.g. `/Users/joe/projects/demo`

Answer (score 4):

Try to test it first:

```
path=$(pwd); echo ${path}
```

If that work, then you can add the docker command:

```
path=$(pwd); docker run -v ${path}:/var/mydir image
```

Also, if you are executing that command from the host shell (Mac), instead of the docker machine shell (through a `docker-machine ssh` session), make sure you have executed `eval "$(docker-machine env <machinename>)"` first.

Comment: so we need determine ${pwd} into any value ? i exptected is directly call -v ${pwd} instead of determine variable=${pwd}; sytnx ${variable}

Comment: @Yor in this specific case, for this OP, it might be necessary to use this workaround. That is why I asked the user to test, 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Using `${PWD}`:

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/src -w /src golang:1.17 go mod download && go run main.go
```